# odbc mysql database locked

Tags: mysql, database, odbc, locked

i'm new to mysql, i'm using odbc to access a mysql database i created. i've noticed one of my other sofware packages uses mysql and once i open my database, the other datbase is locked. i close the connection immediately when i leave my database but the other one stays locked. i don't have access to the 2nd one. the only way i can unlock the other database is a reboot.

any suggestions?

Set oRs15 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set oConn15 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

userid = Sheets("register").Cells(22, 2)
dt = Nothing

DBError:

oConn15.Open connectstr

qry = "select count(*) as the_count from Comps where userid = """ & userid & """"
Set oRs15 = oConn15.Execute(qry)

'do some stuff

Set oRs15 = Nothing
Set oConn15 = Nothing

End Sub